# Playframework 1.2.4 renderPDF : Greek not displayed

Tags: character-encoding, playframework, pdf-generation, playframework-1.x

I am using playframework 1.2.4 and the pdf module 0.9.

When I call render() everything works fine in the generated html file.

However in renderPDF() the Greek characters are not displayed at all.

Anyone else had this problem?

How did you solve it?

Answer (score 2):

Geia,

I think your problem has to do with the font or the encoding (Play!Framework uses only UTF-8) .There are some other configurations that you have to do.

I think you have to add this line on your conf file

```
yahp.FOP_TTF_FONT_PATH = public/ui/fonts
```

and then add the font that you prefer.Try to use DejaVu as font which includes Greek.

If this doesn't work please read this thread.

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/play-framework/Zt7l3-CoY4U

It must be the same problem with yours.

Comment: If this method didn't work please let me know so we can do something else.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working with this issue for a while and I want to clean thins up.

1) You can't specify single file in `yahp.FOP_TTF_FONT_PATH`, it must be **directory** with fonts (for me it's not obvious from the property name). Acceptable format is only .ttf(but you can change otf to ttf)

2) You don't need to make `@font-face` in your css with new font. What you need is to specify in `font-family` property **name that is written in font specification**.